# system() call o/p to filename passed from command line

Tags: c, exec, parent-child, argv

I have this below small code where the file name is passed from command line. This program is getting called by `execlp()` from a different program. I want the o/p of the command getting called by `system()` here into the filename coming as `argv[2]`. Not getting a clue how to do that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char c;

    printf("Received : %s  filename: %s\n",argv[1],argv[2]);
        FILE *fp=fopen(argv[2],"w");

    system("./linked_list");

    printf("Here...\n");
    sleep(5);   
    //sleep(3*atoi(argv[2]));
  return 0;
}
```

The o/p of ./linked_list is simply a list getting printed as below:

```
****printing list****
info :0   address:0x884e068   next:0x884e0c8
info :1   address:0x884e0c8   next:0x884e058
info :2   address:0x884e058   next:0x884e0b8
info :3   address:0x884e0b8   next:0x884e048
info :4   address:0x884e048   next:0x884e0a8
info :5   address:0x884e0a8   next:0x884e038
info :6   address:0x884e038   next:0x884e098
info :7   address:0x884e098   next:0x884e028
info :8   address:0x884e028   next:0x884e088
info :9   address:0x884e088   next:0x884e018
info :10   address:0x884e018   next:0x884e078
info :11   address:0x884e078   next:0x884e008
Last element...  info:12  address:0x884e008   next:(nil)

Child terminating...
```

Comment: Use redirection - `./linked_list > file`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the `system` function calls the shell, so you can use normal shell redirection:

```
char command[64];
snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "./linked_list > %s", argv[2]);
system(command);
```